# Issue using where condition in Laravel with Mongdb

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following data structure. I can use a `where` condition with normal field but not to those in an array.

**Data Structure**

```
Array
(
    [AdjustmentAmount] => Array
        (
            [_] => 0
            [currencyID] => AUD
        )

    [AmountPaid] => Array
        (
            [_] => 0
            [currencyID] => AUD
        )

    [AmountSaved] => Array
        (
            [_] => 0
            [currencyID] => AUD
        )

    [BuyerUserID] => mzkfx400

 [ShippingDetails] => Array
        (
            [SalesTax] => Array
                (
                    [SalesTaxPercent] => 0
                    [SalesTaxState] => 
                    [ShippingIncludedInTax] => 
                    [SalesTaxAmount] => Array
                        (
                            [_] => 0
                            [currencyID] => AUD
                        )

                )

            [ShippingServiceOptions] => Array
                (
                    [ShippingService] => AU_Freight
                    [ShippingServicePriority] => 1
                    [ExpeditedService] => 
                )

            [SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber] => 60340
            [GetItFast] => 
        )

)
```

**this one works**

```
 $ebayOrder = LMongo::collection('ebay_orders')->where('BuyerUserID','mzkfx400')->first();
```

**this does not work**

```
 $ebayOrder = LMongo::collection('ebay_orders')->where('ShippingService','AU_Freight')->first();
```

So basically I want to use where condition for the field inside the array.

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

```
$ebayOrder = LMongo::collection('ebay_orders')->where('ShippingService','AU_Freight')->first();
```

This will not work because ShippingService is not a document instead its inner element. You will have to fetch ShippingDetails and then using foreach iterate over to ShippingService. So query should be like this.

```
$ebayOrder = LMongo::collection('ebay_orders')->where('BuyerUserID','mzkfx400')->first();

 foreach($ebayOrder as $order)
 {
    //Code to loop over to ShippingService.
 }
```